# Units when calculating the gradient

Tags: calculus, gradient-descent

I have a very trivial question, but If I have a variable - bending angle ($ \alpha$) and its unit are radians and If I calculate the gradient of $\alpha $, in which units it's going to be please? The gradient is calculated with the respect to height, so $rad * h^{-1}$?

Comment: What you mean by "gradient of X"? If it's a derivative, then the variable you're differentiating with respect to (the "denominator") also has units. So, for instance, if you're differentiating an angle measure wrt time, then your units would be $\mathrm{rad/s}$. Often, the unit of radian is dropped because it's considered dimensionless (a length divided by a length), so that unit just becomes $\mathrm{s^{-1}}$. But before we get too ahead of ourselves, I think you should provide more context.

Comment: Edited but I think I figured it out thanks to you.